# It is not possible to get props in react when using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I replaced all classes with functions and am trying to get the state in another function. this.props does not see without super(props), and it does not work out to get it otherwise. I ask for help, thank you all very much in advance!

```
// Declaring the state via the useState hook;

    const App = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState([
            {
                label: 'Учу React!',
                important: false,
                like: false,
                id: 1,
            },
    
            {
                label: 'Получается отлично ;)',
                important: false,
                like: false,
                id: 2,
            },
    
            {
                label: 'Не хочу останавливаться',
                important: false,
                like: false,
                id: 3,
            },
        ]);
    
        const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
        const [filter, setFilter] = useState('all');



// Attempt to get an array of data objects



    import React from 'react';
    import App from '../app/app';
    import { createContext } from 'react';
    import './post-list_item.css';
    
    const PostListItem = () => {
        console.log(App.data); // --> undefined
```

Screenshot of the ad code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZFMq.png)

Screenshot of the code of the receiving attempt
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0s2h.png)

Comment: It should just be `setData((data) => {data.findIndex...})` (without curly braces in the function argument). There is no destructuring needed. Also; `PostListItem` are not allowed to access anything inside `App` - since App is not a class. If you need `App`'s data, you need to pass it as props to `PostListItem`

Comment: `PostListItem` needs to have a parameter to pass/accept the props. This aspect should not be that different from class based components and I don't know how you had it working trying to access `App.data`.

Comment: Also, don't post screenshots of code. Instead, include the relevant and minimal example as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access state variable like your code. `App.data` is wrong!

You should use prop drilling to pass the parent data that you want to use in children.

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  return (
    <PostListItem data={data} />
  );
}


const PostListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.data}</div>
  )
}
```